# Is it legal to ask for my information?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, legal

Is it legal for air companies to ask for my personal information?

I mean, today I had to buy a ticket from easy jet.
To do so, I was forced to register to the site, choose a password, 
and to insert some personal information, among which where I live, my telephone
number, my real name, and also the purpose of the trip.

All of this info was compulsory and regarding only the account that I was about to create.

Can they do this?
And can I just ignore them and put on fake information? 
I realise I have to write my real name when it asks me **who is going to travel**, but when it comes to registering on their site, I can write whatever I want or not?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be legal? I don't take on anonymous consulting clients, for example. The low cost carriers milk every revenue option they have and that doubtless includes your personal information - for their own marketing reasons or to sell it. Most traditional airlines have a "continue as guest" option. That EasyJet doesn't means they chose this as a strategy. If you don't like it, don't book with them, I guess.

Comment: @KateGregory if every airline would do so you would be forced to enter you personal information every time you want to travel. "If you don't like just don't use airplanes" is not an answer, the consumer should be protected by governments. Anyhow, is it legal then to fill in with false informations the registration form on the site?

Comment: There's no law stopping you from lying about your personal information.

Comment: @JonathanReez great! can you elaborate more though? For example if the company finds out I lied about it, can they invalidate the account and / or refuse to service me in the future?

Comment: You may find that providing incorrect data is actually illegal in some jurisdictions, as the carrier may have to provide this data to customs etc.!

Comment: @JonathanReez: Actually, there most certainly is. That's called fraud, and is highly illegal in most places. Whether you would get caught is another matter.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about online privacy, and not about travel.

Comment: @Flimzy from Wikipedia: "Fraud is a deception deliberately practiced in order to secure unfair or unlawful gain". If you gain nothing from the lie, there's no way they could prosecute you in court.

Comment: @Flimzy: the cases in your link are about a person who bullied a teenager into killing herself. That's a much bigger "gain" than an online account.

Such an absurd law would also mean that it's illegal to lie to Starbucks baristas about your name. After all, you "gain" a cup of coffee after telling them which name to write on the cup.

Comment: Whether this is legal or not depends on the locale where the business entity you're dealing with is located and the locale where you're located. Furthermore this isn't really a travel-related question since the same question would apply to any other online vendor.

Comment: @Flimzy: if we're being *that* strict, wouldn't "throwaway ticketing" be a crime as well since it violates the airline's terms of service? While I'm sure the government could interpret the law in any way it likes, there have been no real life cases of someone being put in jail for lying without commiting actual fraud.

Comment: @Flimzy: even the strictest legal definition of identity fraud would require some sort of provable malice/mens rea. Failing to reveal your address for the sake of privacy is a victimless crime and thus impossible to prosecute. It's also impossible to argue identity theft, since you aren't trying to impersonate a different person.

Comment: @Flimzy: 1) Like I said above - it's possible to interpret the law in any way the government sees fit. Only the judge and the jury can you protect you from that, or any of the hundreds of other ridiculous laws each of us is facing in daily life 2) "Fraud" has a very specific definition in US federal law, which states that there must be a net positive gain for you in order for something to be constituted as fraud 3) If failing to provide one's address is not a crime, then OP's question can be closed with a definite "no". He's obviously okay with giving his name to the airline.

Comment: I would really start a conversation here, but apparently this is not the place. Can someone suggest a site where this question would be well received?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The legality of asking for personal information when setting up an online account varies greatly by location, and is not the least bit related to travel.

In the US, for instance, it is legal to ask such information--provided the person answering the questions is at least 13 years of age, or has parental consent.

In Canada, my understanding is, it is illegal to *require* personal information that is *not necessary for performing the service requested*.

Other localities will of course have different rules.

And the rules as they relate to access over the Internet get even more confusing...  And still not the least bit on-topic for this site.

Comment: Canada's act http://www.priv.gc.ca/information/guide_e.asp is pretty generous about "necessary" - identifying the customer, establishing creditworthiness, and tracking interactions to provide better customer service are all given as examples of good reasons to ask for this info. The bar is not "I couldn't serve you without the info", not at all

Comment: Isn't there some contradiction between (rather condescendingly) arguing it's all off-topic and yet offering an answer?